# how to read an http request(an http proxy server)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, http, pointers

I have to make an http proxy. In the proxy side I have to parse the http request sent by the user.

The question is: How to read binary data from the client such at the final I will  get an array of char that contains the full request .

What I did is: Read 1 Byte each time.

```
    char c;
    int  n = read(con,&c,1);
```

I saw many implementation where we use 1024 bytes as the size of the buffer , but are we sure that the size of the request will not exceeds  1024?

Normally in first place I have to allocate the memory for the buffer array , so how can i know the size of the request to allocate the same size of memory?

My full methods:

```
void readToken(int con,char *token){
char c;
int i=0;
do{
    int  n = read(con,&c,1);
    *token++ = c;
    }while(c!=' ' && c!='\n');      
}

void readLine(int con,char *line){
    char c;int i=0;
    do{
        int  n = read(con,&c,1);
        *line++ = c;
        }while(c!='\n');

}
char * handleRequest(int con){
    char resource[30];
    char version[5];
    char  method[4] ;
    //i read 4 byte to get the method tyepe 
    int n = read(con,&method,4);
    //here i read until i get a blank space
    readToken(con,resource);
    //readToken(con,version);
    printf("the method is%s\n",method);
    printf("the resource asked is%s\n",resource);
    //printf("the resource asked is%s\n",version);
    printf("the method read is %s",firstLine);
    readLine(con,hostLine);
    printf("the method read is %s",hostLine);       
}
```

Comment: "are we sure that the size of the request will not exceeds 1024?" No. If I recall correctly the standard says nothing about size. The browsers has limits between 4 and 11 kBs.

Comment: The buffer should just be for efficiency of reading. You should keep filling the buffer in a loop until the whole request has been received (or timeout/error etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading by a single character is terribly inefficient and slows you down tremendously. Instead, you should be reading by chunks of approriate size (1024 seems as good initial guess as any) in the loop and append read buffer to the total data read so far. It is extremely easy to do with C++ `std::vector`.

Comment: thanks , how can i append the new incoming data in C ? i think if i loop and read to the buffer i will overwrite the preceding data.

Comment: @jeanjack, in C you would have to use something like `realloc` to keep increasing your buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing an HTTP request is a quite complicated task, I think it could be easier to use a library like [http-parser](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser), which does the parsing for you in a very efficient way.